# Angular fieldset dinamic able disabled after click after chromeLastUpdate do not work

Tags: angular, fieldset, disabled-control

following the chrome upgrade I have a fieldset nested inside two divs everything is created dynamically with an ngFor in a top div so everything is nested inside a div where ngFor runs now we have filedset 0 / 1 / 2 at the start only the 0 if I click on the title of the fieldset the fieldset is enabled, I want it to be enabled even if I click for example on the radio of an element of a fieldset I am not able to do it here is a stackblitz with a very basic example I noticed that the question does not work on the latest version of chrome on other browsers everything is fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahftan?

Answer (score 0):

in Mozzilla Firefox is the same situation

Comment: This is not an answer.